# Rotate object in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, accelerometer

I can use the following code to rotate object using accelerometer.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Input.acceleration.normalized, Vector3.up);
```

But i would like to rotate object like for example screen is rotating - 0, 90, 180 and 360 degrees. How can I do it using Unity 3D?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `transform.rotation` like this:

```
transform.rotation = new Quaternion(rotx, roty, rotz, rotw);
```

**OR**

You can use `transform.Rotate` like this:

```
transform.Rotate(rotx, roty, rotz);
```

[Documentation for Quaternion](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)

[Documentation for transform.rotation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)

Example for Rotating screen with accelerometer input:

```
float accelx, accely, accelz = 0;

void Update ()
{
    accelx = Input.acceleration.x;
    accely = Input.acceleration.y;
    accelz = Input.acceleration.z;
    transform.Rotate (accelx * Time.deltaTime, accely * Time.deltaTime, accelz * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

If you want to rotate the object to a specific angle use:

```
float degrees = 90;
Vector3 to = new Vector3(degrees, 0, 0);

transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, to, Time.deltaTime);
```

This will rotate 90 degrees around the x axis.

Comment: I din't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links but just google transform.Rotate if you need to read some documentation on that too.

Comment: It still doesn't give me a solution for this problem. I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: Explain what exactly do you want to do

Comment: "example screen is rotating - 0, 90, 180 and 360 degrees" on which axis (x, y or z)? Using accelerometer input ?

Comment: I would like to auto-rotate one object in my scene using accelerometer as i said before. Do you know how screen auto rotation is working? I would like to do the same with only one object on my scene.

Comment: You mean from landscape to portrait and vice versa ?

Comment: Btw to rotate the screen you rotate the camera and camera is a gameobject like any other and work in the same way. So it don't matter what gameobject you rotate, the code is the same.

Comment: Yes I mean from portrait to landscape and vice versa. I know there is option in unity to rotate all the app, but I need to rotate only 1 object.

Comment: Then rotate just 1 object unsing the transform.eulerAngles to rotate it to the desired angle

Comment: Unity Docs Link: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Answer (score 5):

In order to rotate your game object on its own

```
int _rotationSpeed = 15;

void Update () {

    // Rotation on y axis
    // be sure to capitalize Rotate or you'll get errors
    transform.Rotate(0, _rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to add this to a game object where you can drop the game object into the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TheNameOfYourScriptHere : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 100;
    
    public GameObject yourgameobject;
    
    void Update()
    {
          yourgameobject.transform.Rotate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Please note this rotation is faster so you can see it better in action.

Answer (score -1):

You can rotate your object via just adding below line in your .cs script.

transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,Here you can put horizonatl speed);