# Unity - Rotate a cube in multiple directions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am able to rotate a cube in multiple directions using this code :

```
public float speed = 100f;
public Animation anim;
Animator animator;

public Vector3 RotateAmount;

bool running = false;

void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("up"))
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, speed);
    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed);
    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, speed);
    if (Input.GetKey("down"))
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, speed);
}
```

Now what i want is to rotate a cube no matter which face is in front. But above code does not do that.If i press a then it rotates right but then when i press right it rotates left. This is what i want to avoid. Can someone help me in figuring out the logic or any idea?

Beginner with unity pls.

Comment: i was far from unity for long time, and i hardly understand what you are saying... but maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648071/rotate-object-in-unity-3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should multiply `speed` with `Time.deltaTime` else your rotation speed will be dependent on the current framerate.

You are probably adding rotation in local space which messes everything up.

**RotateScript.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateScript : MonoBehaviour
{

float speed = 100f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("up"))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(this.transform.position, new Vector3(1, 0, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("down"))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(this.transform.position, new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(this.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(this.transform.position, new Vector3(0, -1, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
}
```

This code is rotating the cube around its current position in the world `this.transform.position` (If you use a different model make sure this point is the center of the object, else the rotation will look weird).

In the case of objects that are not modelled with the origin as center you can try `transform.renderer.bounds.center` to get the center.

Comment: i don't know why but i replaced my update code with yours and the whole scene just freezes whenever i play it and press any direction key.

Comment: Have you tried my code in a new project? What version of unity are you using?

Comment: sorry just used GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center and it seems to work. Thanks a lot and it works perfectly now. Right moves right and not up or something after few rotations. Thanks for code too. Just one more thing. How do i make sure that one face becomes another in one go? That way i won't have vertices in rotation and it will be smooth (trying to make a puzzle solver).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you want to do some crazy math with the vertices, you can access them with `Mesh.vertices`. You maybe want to create a new question for that because it sounds like something very specific that doesn't fit in a comment.