# How do I rotate an object on the Y axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game with a 'rotating' Earth, but I don't know how to rotate...  This is what I've got so far, help would be much appreciated:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Earth_Rotation : MonoBehaviour
{
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
     Transform.Rotate (0, 10, 0);
     }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate object in Unity 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648071/rotate-object-in-unity-3d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the `Rotate()` method on your objects transform component. Uppercase `Transform`refers to the `Transform` class itself where lowercase `transform`refers to this objects instance of a transform component. If you want to manipulate the object your script is attached to you need lowercase `transform`. I suggest checking out this link to learn about classes and objects: [Class and Object - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-class-and-object/)

Further, if you want your object to turn over time, you need to reference the time somewhere. This can be achieved via `Time.deltaTime` which returns the time passed since the last frame in Unity. Try something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    //Vector3.up is a vector that looks like this: (0,1,0)
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

You can also add a modifier like `public float turnSpeed` and multiply by that to increase or decrease your objects turn speed:

```
public float turnSpeed;

void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
}
```

If you set `turnSpeed = 10` you have your original value.

Always take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) for the functions you are trying to use. It helps a lot to understand how and where to use them.