# Rotate an object in X and Y axis with mouse drag or touch in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that rotates an object in the Y axis but how do I rotate the object in the X axis as well? For example, if mouse-drag/touch is moving Left/Right, it should rotate in Y direction and if its moving up/down, it should rotate in X direction.

```
public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _sensitivity;
    private Vector3 _mouseReference;
    private Vector3 _mouseOffset;
    private Vector3 _rotation;
    private bool _isRotating;

    void Start()
    {
        _sensitivity = 0.4f;
        _rotation = Vector3.zero;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (_isRotating)
        {
            // offset
            _mouseOffset = (Input.mousePosition - _mouseReference);

            // apply rotation
            _rotation.y = -(_mouseOffset.x + _mouseOffset.y) * _sensitivity;

            // rotate
            transform.Rotate(_rotation);

            // store mouse
            _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // rotating flag
        _isRotating = true;

        // store mouse
        _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        // rotating flag
        _isRotating = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Asked very often already. In short: Rather have a parent object and do Y rotation only on the parent. And do the X rotation only on the child.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate object in Unity 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648071/rotate-object-in-unity-3d)