# Rotate Character based on Vector3 moveDirection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character that moves along the `x-world-axis` if i press A/D and along the `z-world-axis` if i press W/S.

I want my character to look into that direction that he moves to. E.g. if the player presses "D", the character should look to the right.

My script looks something like:

```
Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
moveDirection *= moveSpeed;
...
```

and so on.

What is the best way to rotate that character into the direction he's currently moving?

Comment: I don't use Unity, but perhaps this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648071/rotate-object-in-unity-3d

Comment: @MikeH not exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think the comment provided by MikeH is actually what you were looking for.

```
Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
moveDirection *= moveSpeed;
transform.position += moveDirection;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection, Vector3.up);
```

The above will move your object in the X/Z plane based on WASD input and will rotate the object so its facing the direction its moving.